# How can I copy specific cells(with Value,Color,Font) from one excel file to another excel file C#?

Tags: c#, excel

Here I have used this code from copying cells from one excel file to another. But it take lot of time.

```
     for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 10;j++) {  
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].style.Font.Color = ws.Cells[i, i].style.Font.Color;
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].Interior.Color = ws.Cells[i, i].Interior.Color;
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = ws.Cells[i, i];
            }
        }
```

Is there any other method available?

Comment: It's always recommended to check MSDN documentation: [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.copy?view=excel-pia)

Comment: `ws.Cells[i, i]` don't you mean `ws.Cells[i, j]` instead?

Comment: @Rafalon It just example

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation: [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.copy?view=excel-pia)

If you would like to copy only text or formatting (etc.), then use `PasteSpecial` together with `Copy` method: [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial?view=excel-pia)

Usage:

```
//define cells (range) to copy
Excel.Range from = srcworkSheet.Range["A1:D100"];
//define destination range
Excel.Range to = destworkSheet.Range["A1"];
from.Copy(to);

//this should also works:
//xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].Copy(ws.Cells[i, j]);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I got this error when srcworksheet.Range("A1:D1") used.. CS1955 Non-invocable member '_Worksheet.Range[object, object]' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Sorry. I've used wrong brackets (VBA habit). See: [Worksheet.Range property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range?view=vsto-2017)

Comment: Error 'Copy method of Range class failed'